# What is needed to share printers with Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, printer, terminal-services

Ok so we are trying to get a few computers across the state running Remote Desktop/Terminal Server. The way we intend is that they do a remote desktop to a remote server and from there can use an application and such and print reports or whatever they need.

My problem is that sometimes the printers do not show up and sometimes they do on the remote server. For instance two computers are side by side and have the same printer setup. On one computer you can login to the terminal server and it shows all the printers in the printers control panel page. On the other computer it does not show any printers. What prevents them from being shared from this one computer?

The only differences I'm seeing is that the one that works has SP3 and the one that doesn't has SP2. Both are Windows XP Professional x86. Is there something more light than SP3 that I can install to fix only this problem? Also I've tried installing SP3 on some computers and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Also, both computers have .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed.

Also, a bit more info: The printer for both computers is a network printer. Same printer for both computers and they are on the same network.

Comment: The RDP client in SP3 is different for sure. However, I'm sure you can install it separately on SP2 systems. Not sure it will help, but it will at least rule something out and avoid having to install SP3. On the other hand, Microsoft just stopped developing security patches for SP2, so you really should install SP3 soon.

Comment: @boot well we aren't the IT department or anything. We are just trying to get our proprietary software up and running, preferably without having to fix up all of their computers.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ideas...

Make sure the RDP shortcut on each computer has the local printer attach enabled.

Ensure that the printer drivers on all the clients machines exactly match the ones on the terminal server.  If their names or versions vary then the printer won't be associated on the RDP server when the connection is made and won't show up.

Comment: The printer drivers match on both and printer sharing is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Besides the things mentioned by techie007 are you logging off of sessions, or disconnecting? 
If you login as the same user from a disconnected session you may not be completely re-detecting resources.

If the computers are essentially the same how are the user login credentials, possibly differences in a user profile?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using TS Easy Print then the client computer needs to have the same driver that the server does.

If you are using TS Easy Print then make sure you meet the [minimum requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753853(WS.10).aspx) on the client and server.